# android sending intent extra

Tags: java, android, listview, android-intent

App reads JSON data. Then it would put it to whe listview (correctly) but after pressing an item I would always get the same value showed. Below the code where I think is the problem but I can't find one.

```
try{
    JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
    for(int ii=0;ii<jArray.length();ii++){
            JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(ii);
            courseName = json_data.getString("fullname");

            HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            map.put("fullname", courseName);
            myCoursesList.add(map);
    }
} catch(JSONException e){
    Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
}
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, myCoursesList,R.layout.my_courses_layout,
        new String[] {"fullname"}, new int[] { R.id.course});

setListAdapter(adapter);
ListView lv = getListView();
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
        String fn = ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.course)).getText().toString();

        Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), courseActivity.class);
        in.putExtra("fullname", fn);
        startActivity(in);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
String fn = ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.course)).getText().toString();
```

To this:

```
String fn = ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.course)).getText().toString();
```

Comment: Thanks it worked (I will accept answer in 7 minutes) Maybe you could explain it what's the difference?

Comment: When you click an item, its view is returned as parameter in **onItemClick**, so you need to use that view to perform findViewById in order to get the selected row's TextView

Answer (score 1):

I a normal adapter / listview, I suppose you would want to do something like this.

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
     String fn = adapter.get(position);
     Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), courseActivity.class);
     in.putExtra("fullname", fn);
     startActivity(in);      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
String fn = ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.course)).getText().toString();
```

instead of

```
String fn = ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.course)).getText().toString();
```